# Unable to perform s3 copy using boto3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto, boto3

I've written this piece of code which should do a copy in S3.

```
import boto3    
s3client = boto3.client('s3', config['AWS']['Region'])
source = {'Bucket': bucket_name, 'Key': source_key}
metadata = {'a':'b'}
s3client.copy_object(Bucket=bucket_name, CopySource=source, Key=target_key, Metadata=metadata)
```

But the error that I get is

> ClientError: An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the CopyObject operation: Access Denied

Although I do have access to s3. If I do an upload or list operations it works. Only copy_object throws this error. I'm running out of ideas on why this isn't working.

Comment: Does the IAM role you're running with allow copy object of the source object and allow write to the target bucket?

Comment: Can you try it with the AWS CLI - i.e. 'aws s3 cp s3://source-bucket-name/key s3//target-bucket-name/key'?  That would allow you to fix any authentication problems without boto in the mix first.

Comment: Yeah I'm able to copy it with the cli

Comment: @jarmod Yes it has access, as I'm able to do operations via the cli

Comment: AccessDenied indicates that you don't have permission so you need to work out if it's an API permission problem, a bucket permission problem, a coding problem, or problems with the environment that your code is running in (i.e. its effective credentials). Might be worth making the source object world-readable and the target bucket world-writable temporarily and re-test. Then work up the chain from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the problem was i was trying to access the wrong bucket. And hence the error.So the error was actually correct.